# Is there any plugin for After Effects to create a 'kinetic typography' video?

Tags: video, after-effects

I was looking at some kinetic typography videos - like the one below - and wondering whether there is a plugin for Adobe After Effects CS4 that can help with this. If not, then is there any other easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of 2011, there aren't plugins that assemble a typography video for you, because this kind of work is really a sub-topic of motion graphics.  There are tools that can help you with camera animation and rigging in AE though.

My favorite is Video Copilot's [Sure Target 2](http://www.videocopilot.net/tutorials/sure_target_2/), which lets you think about the animation in terms of what you're looking **at**, instead of thinking about it in terms of camera perspective.  This makes the work feel similar to using something like Cinema4D's target camera.

Another noteworthy tutorial: http://ae.tutsplus.com/tutorials/motion-graphics/design-rhythmic-motion-typography-in-after-effects/

> If not, then is there any other easy way to do this?

Not really.  Watch [lots of videos](http://www.marcofolio.net/video/15_stunning_motion_typography_videos.html), take notes on ideas you like, steal the best, and [trust in what is difficult](http://the99percent.com/articles/6977/Rainer-Maria-Rilke-Trust-In-What-Is-Difficult).

Answer (score 2):

TypeMonkey will help you a lot when trying to create kinetic text animations. http://aescripts.com/typemonkey/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any plugins, but I think it's probably possible to do just with After Effect itself. You may have already seen these, but here's a few articles on the subject.

- Crooked Gremlins [Kinetic Typography Article](http://www.bitrebels.com/geek/how-to-make-kinetic-typography/) (there's also a [video version](http://vimeo.com/1271357))
- BitRebels [How To Make Kinetic Typography](http://www.crookedgremlins.com/09/01/2008/kinetic-typography-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use some scripts for camery keyframes, to get those type of ease or rushing camera effect, but it realy depends on how good your typography and idea is.